# OpenSSL verify server certificate

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, networking, openssl

I am new in openssl and i have TLS client code but doubt about certificate validation. In this code nothing about certificate validation. It is hidden process which executed behind the scene or just code is bad?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define FAIL    -1

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{   int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{   SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
    SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
    method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
    if ( ctx == NULL )
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}

int main(int count, char *strings[])
{   SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;
    char buf[1024];
    int bytes;
    char *hostname, *portnum;

    if ( count != 3 )
    {
        printf("usage: %s <hostname> <portnum>\n", strings[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    SSL_library_init();
    hostname=strings[1];
    portnum=strings[2];

    ctx = InitCTX();
    server = OpenConnection(hostname, atoi(portnum));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {   char *msg = "Hello???";

        printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certs */
        SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));   /* encrypt & send message */
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        printf("Received: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */
    }
    close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

Hope anyone read this code and give me some information for understanding certificate validation processes.

Comment: OpenSSL will not verify the certificate by default, neither trust chain nor hostname nor certificate revocation. See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client for https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation code examples which include validation. Revocation checking is even more complex.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But then how it works? As i know, TLS protocol requires certificate validation. If validation is not perform, how then it works?

Comment: TLS protocol by itself does not require certificate validation, it does not even require certificates in the first place. But, to protect against MITM attacks one must make sure that the peer is properly authenticated. Certificates are the common but not the only way to do this. It is expected that the application deals with this, i.e. you have to program it yourself. But I fully agree that it is a bad and dangerous design decision to work *by default* without proper validation. Disabling validation should be an explicit and rarely used decision instead, not the default.

Comment: Thank you. As i understand, for verify the server, i just need add hostname validation and that is enough for secure communication? For this i think i need first of all call SSL_get_verify_result function and check result is equals to X509_V_OK. If OK, get certificate using SSL_get_peer_certificate and check hostname by calling X509_check_host. If OK, may i think the secure connection established?

Comment: Thank you again. Sorry, i think i have a last question :) I am using TCP server without HTTP. In this case it is safe to skip certificate validation or MiTM attack will be present? In HTTP case, DNS poisoning attack present, but i am doubt about certificate validation when HTTP is not used (only TCP).

Comment: DNS poisoning is not specific to HTTP but applies to every kind of connectivity where a hostname is used as a target for connection instead of directly an IP address. This includes lots of uses of TCP, UDP, ... . And even without DNS spoofing being a danger other ways for MITM exists, like ARP spoofing, compromised router ... . Thus proper authentication of the peer is important in all of these cases.

Comment: *"i just need add hostname validation and that is enough for secure communication?"*- hostname validation, trust chain validation against locally trusted root CA and preferably also check for certificate revocation - although many skip the latter and it might be sufficiently secure with short-lived certificates.

Comment: Sorry, if i am not use HTTP, just TCP communication using IP:Port of server, in this case, which value of domain i need to speficy for self-signed certificate (in HTTP case, i can specify www.domain.tld, but in only TCP case what i need specify in certificate domain field?)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244146/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-john).